# Export multiple variable from .ts file and import into another file in angular 4

Tags: angular, variables, export

I want to create `config.ts` file which stores the global values of my app. 
For that I'm able to used it by this way.

`module.exports.key = "My key";` But I need export multiple values approx 20-30.
So is there any way? so I don't have to write `module.exports` every time...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do something like this:

In your **config.ts**:

```
export const Keys = {
    KEY_1: 'KEY_1_VALUE',
    KEY_2: 'KEY_2_VALUE'
};
```

Then in the file that you importing it you can do below:

```
import { Keys } from './config';
Keys.KEY_1 //return the value 'KEY_1_value'
```

Comment: Happy that I could help :)

Comment: What if he wants to make the same call but instead of calling Keys.KEY_1, he wants to call KEY_1, how would the import be in that case ? Thanks in advance.